# SpringBoot Failed to configure a DataSource

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm currently learning microservices. After creating my first microservice, I tried to connect my microservice to a PostgreSQL database but I have the following error:

```
Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
```

With this exception:

> Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling
> refresh attempt:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer'
> defined in class path resource
> [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]:
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method
> 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' parameter 0; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource
> [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]:
> Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method
> 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is
> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException:
> Failed to determine a suitable driver class 
> 2022-12-06 22:33:04.408  INFO 2012 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]

Here's my application.yml

```yaml
server:
  port: 8080

spring:
  application:
    name: player
    datasource:
      password: "MySecretPassword!"
      url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/genjiservices
      username: saucegenji
      jpa:
        hibernate:
          ddl-auto: update
        properties:
          hibernate:
            dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
            format_sql: true
        show-sql: true
```

I couldn't post my pom because it says it was a spam.

I tried to find solutions first, but couldn't find one that works for me. I think my application is ignoring my application.yml could that be the case? My application.yml is in the resources folder like it should be, so I don't really understand.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the following is present in the pom file.Also check for JPA dependencies in pom.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hi yes I have that in the pom of my microservice here's the pom `
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>
   <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
   </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>`

I have spring-boot-starter-web, data-jpa, postgres